# href='geo:' for navigation with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I am developing a phonegap app. One button I want to open the mobile's navigation system.

When I do `<a href='geo:xxx,xxx'>` it opens for example Google Maps with the right location. But it does not set a marker at the location and so I cannot start navigation to this location.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You have to use a location plugin for that.

Comment: That's how geo:xxx,xxx works, right? use googlemaps url like that instead "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + lat + ',' + lng + "("+ label +")&z=15"